# appending to a list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my appinventor app, I use a webviewer to view an html page, which contains a listview. Now, I have exactly ten list items and I wrote them in the html code. If I have 12 items in my list which is `urlArray.length=12` in the code, is there a way I could append items to the list like the following?

```
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(10);"><img src="write.png" id="listimg9" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore9" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname9"> Test Name 9 </h1>
<p id="testexp9">Test Explanation 9</p>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

as you can see in the code, for the 11th item in the list `datasent(10)` should be `datasent(11)`, `id="listimg9"` should be `id="listimg10"`, `id="testscore9"` should be `id="testscore10"`, `id="testname9"` should be `id="testname10"` and `id="testexp9"` should be `id="testexp10"`

If there is a better solution, like generating the list depending on how long the `urlArray` is, it would be a better solution but currently, I don't have any idea how to place those id tags inside li items other than typing.

```js
<script>
var datasent = function (listindex) {
 window.AppInventor.setWebViewString(listindex);
 };
 
var wvdata = window.AppInventor.getWebViewString().split('\n');
var urlArray = [];
for (var i in wvdata){
 urlArray.push(wvdata[i].split('%'));
}

for (var s=0; s<urlArray.length; s++) {
    var tn = "testname";
 var ts = "testscore";
 var te = "testexp";
 var im = "listimg";
  var testnamer = tn.concat(s);
  document.getElementById(testnamer).innerHTML = urlArray[s][2];
  var testscorer = ts.concat(s);
  document.getElementById(testscorer).innerHTML = urlArray[s][3];
  var testexper = te.concat(s);
   if (urlArray[s][1]==="mc"){
   document.getElementById(testexper).innerHTML = "Choose the correct answer!";
   }
   else {
   var imer = im.concat(s);
   document.getElementById(testexper).innerHTML = "Fill in the blanks!";
   document.getElementById(imer).src="write.png";
   }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>List App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="photos" class="wrapper">
 <header data-role="header" data-theme="b">
  <h1> Tests </h1>
 </header>

   <article data-role="content" style="background: #000000 url('bg2.jpg') repeat;">
 
  <ul 
  class="tests-list" 
  data-role="listview"
  data-inset="true"
  data-theme="b"
  data-count-theme="a"
  
  
>
<li>
<a href="#" onclick="datasent(1);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg0" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore0" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h2 id="testname0"> Test Name 0</h2>
<p id="testexp0">Test Explanation 0</p>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#dog" onclick="datasent(2);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg1" alt "Min Pin" /><span id="testscore1" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname1">Test Name 1</h1>
<p id="testexp1">Test Explanation 1</p>
</a> 
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(3);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg2" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore2" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname2"> Test Name 2 </h1>
<p id="testexp2">Test Explanation 2</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(4);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg3" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore3" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname3"> Test Name 3 </h1>
<p id="testexp3">Test Explanation 3</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(5);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg4" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore4" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname4"> Test Name 4 </h1>
<p id="testexp4">Test Explanation 4</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(6);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg5" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore5" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname5"> Test Name 5 </h1>
<p id="testexp5">Test Explanation 5</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(7);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg6" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore6" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname6"> Test Name 6 </h1>
<p id="testexp6">Test Explanation 6</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(8);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg7" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore7" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname7"> Test Name 7 </h1>
<p id="testexp7">Test Explanation 7</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(9);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg8" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore8" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname8"> Test Name 8 </h1>
<p id="testexp8">Test Explanation8</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(10);"><img src="write.png" id="listimg9" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span id="testscore9" class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h1 id="testname9"> Test Name 9 </h1>
<p id="testexp9">Test Explanation 9</p>
</a>
</li>
</ul>

</article>
```

Comment: use classes , no need for all the incremental ID's. Use `data-` attribute for whatever ID you need. Traverse within sections (li) based on classes

Comment: I upvoted, sounds like a solid answer, but I really don't know how to do that. An example link maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The below starts with a list that has 10 items in it.

It loops through an array holding 12 items adding those items to the list.

I have taken out all of your elements' incremental ids and used classes instead.

I have modified your `datasent()` function to show you how you can access the elements using their classes and the index of the clicked list item

```js
// I dont know what is in the array you mention or how it is formed 
// so ill just make one up to use here
var arr = ["worms", "Gummy Worms", "15", "Test Name", "Test Explanation" ];
var listItemsArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
  listItemsArr.push(arr);
}
// `listItemsArr` is now a multidemensioanl array holding 12 of the above arrays
// Ill use this to simulate the array of 12 items you say you have

// loop through your array of 12 objects
$(listItemsArr).each(function(index, elem){
   // here ill get all the values from this object in the array 
   // yours will depend on your array
   var href = elem[0];
   var altTxt = elem[1];
   var count = elem[2];
   var testName = elem[3];
   var expln = elem[4];
   
   // create the list item we're going to add
   // again this will depend on what is in your actual array
   var li = '<li>'+
            '<a href="#'+href+'" ><img src="" class="listimg" alt="'+altTxt+'"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >'+count+'</span>'+
            '<h1 class="testname">'+testName+'</h1>'+
            '<p class="testexp">'+expln+'</p>'+
            '</a>'+
            '</li>';
   $('#myList').append(li);
  
});



var datasent = function (listindex) {
  // im not sure what your function here does 
  // im going to use this function to show you that you can get data 
  // from your elements without all the sequential ids by using classes 
  
  // this line gets an array of all the elements with the `testscore` class
  // grabs the element in that array at the index passed in as `listindex`
  // then gets the html from that element
  var testscore = $('.testscore:eq('+listindex+')').html();
  
  var testname = $('.testname:eq('+listindex+')').html();
  var testexp = $('.testexp:eq('+listindex+')').html();
  var listimgalt = $('.listimg:eq('+listindex+')').attr('alt');
  var listimghref = $('#myList a:eq('+listindex+')').attr('href');
  
  var ourInfo ='You clicked list item at index:  ' + listindex+'\n'+
               'This item\'s image alt text is:  ' + listimgalt+'\n'+
               'This item\'s link href is:  ' + listimghref+'\n'+
               'This item\'s testscore is:  ' + testscore+'\n'+
               'This item\'s testname is:  ' + testname+'\n'+
               'This item\'s testexp is:  ' + testexp+'\n';

  alert(ourInfo);
  
};


// attach a click handeler to all `li`s in `#myList`
$(document).on('click', '#myList li', function(){ 
    // get the index of the clicked link 
    var cur = $('#myList li').index(this);
    // call `datasent()` passing in our index
 datasent( cur );
})
```

```css
img{
 content:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-5/256/unit-completed-icon.png");
    width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.ui-li-count{
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:20px;
  
  }

#myList{
  
    list-style-type: none;
  }

a{
  
  text-decoration:none !important;
  color:#666666;
  }

#myList li{
  
   background-color:#ccc;
   padding:20px;
   width:50%;
   margin-top:10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>  
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" ><img src=""  class="listimg" alt="Gummy Bears"/><span class="testscore ui-li-count" >2</span>
<h1 class="testname"> Test Name  </h1>
<p class="testexp">Test Explanation </p>
</a>
</li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I started studying this. I'll mark it as correct ans. as soon as I make it work.

Comment: my datasent function was to send the data (for example, 1) back to appinventor, so I'd knew which list item was selected. I see that the onclick (<a href="#" onclick="datasent(1);">, as in the html) is gone. if I place it in the listitems.each function, would there be any problems with it?

Comment: one last thing, aren't I supposed to see the array items ["worms", "Gummy Worms", "15", "Test Name", "Test Explanation" ] when I run the  code snippet?

Comment: I have replaced `onclick="datasent(10);"`  that was on each element with one click handler `$(document).on('click', '#myList li' function()` which will call `datasent()` any time an `li` inside your list is clicked and automatically pass in the index of the clicked `li`.  I created a `datasent()` function just to show you how to access the various element. Your actual `datasent` function should continue to work as it did before just leave mine out of your code. As for the elements that show on the alert, I was just leaving off those two, I edited my answer so it shows them and is more clear :)

Comment: hey, are you sure you posted this at the correct place? your jsfiddle example made me feel like I want to give up the whole thing.. also, +g+ What is g? Where do we declare that?

Comment: Oh man, sorry, yeah that was for a different question I'll delete it!